# i am trying to send data into multiple url and send mail from that url

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to send data into 2 different url and on that url i did create mail function for check is thsi work but not working my code is 
url array is :-

```
$fields = array("product" => 'post1',"orderid" => 'roder1');
$url = array( 'http://test.com/core/curl-excute.php', 'http://test2.in/external-curl.php' );

$fields_string ='';//http_build_query($_POST);    
foreach($fields as $key => $value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

foreach( $url as $value ) {
if( !empty( $value ) ) {

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_URL, $value);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($handle);

curl_close ($handle);
}
}
```

Comment: i am getting mail only from one url not from both

Comment: @NirojAdhikary While OP isn't using `$key` in the loop it doesn't matter whether it is there or not, it is not causing the code to fail.

Comment: please check above edited code using this i am getting only one file location not both

Comment: yes its work now yhank you @NirojAdhikary